# SQLite3 export Data

Tags: python, sqlite, csv, export-to-csv

I am currently working on a python projekt with tensorflow and I need to preprocess my data.

The data I want to use is stored in an sqlite3 database with the columns:

```
timestamp|dev|event
10:00    |01 | on
11:00    |02 | off
11:15    |01 | off
11:30    |02 | on
```

And I would like to export the Data into a file (.csv) looking like that:

```
Timestamp|01 |02 |...
10:00    |on |0  |...
11:00    |on |off|...
11:15    |off|off|...
11:30    |off|on |...
```

Which always has the latest information of every Device associated with the current timestamp and with every new timestamp the old values should stay and if there is an update only those value(s) should be updated. 
The number of Devices does not change and I can find that number with

```
SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT dev) FROM table01;
```

Currently that Number is 38 diffrent devices and a total of 10000 entries.

Is there a way to to this computation with sqlite3 or do I have to write a program in python to process the data. I am new to both topics.

~Fabian

Comment: I think you're better off doing the output transformation in python.

Answer (score 0):

You can work it in sqlite, something along this lines

```
select 
    timestamp, 
    group_concat(case when dev="01" then event else "" end, "") as D01, 
    group_concat(case when dev="02" then event else "" end, "") as D02  
from 
    table01 
group by 
    timestamp;
```

Basically you are pivoting the table.

Challenges are, as the pivot needs to be kind of dynamic i.e. the list of the devices are not fixed. You need to query the list of devices and then build this query i.e. case when else part based on the list of the devices.

Also, generally you need to group based on the timestamp, as for device status for different devices will be in different row for a single timestamp.

Also if the {timestamp, device} is not unique you need make it unique.